# Connect AWS s3 with django

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, django-staticfiles

I'm testing my django project on s3 locally. But when running the server it doesn't seem to be serving static files

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.getenv('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.getenv('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.getenv('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = 'public-read'
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = f'{AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME}.s3.amazonaws.com'
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400'}
# s3 static settings
AWS_LOCATION = 'static'
STATIC_URL = f'https://{AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/{AWS_LOCATION}/'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

But it doesn' t seem working
when I check my browser's console it shows http error code of 403 request forbidden when accessing to  my static files. why this happens, should I change my s3 settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this error can be of the s3 side. check if you have permission to access objects and buckets. as i see your settings, you are using django-storages. not django-s3-storages. their are some changes in between.
for me personally, in case of django-storages; by adding region name to the setting helped.so make sure that you also included
`AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = 'the region here'`

hope it works for you too.

Comment: Thanks for Your help I have put the region. But I figured that the problem is with the permission for accessing objects from the bucket